# Windows exe, bat, cmd not launching under cygwin /MobaXterm unless extension explicitly provided

Tags: cygwin

I am using a preconfigured cygwin that is packaged into the MobaXterm product.   Following is an example of the issue I am facing:

```
$ sbt package
/usr/bin/bash: /drives/c/apps/sbt/bin/sbt: No such file or directory
```

The actual command that should have been invoked is:

```
/drives/c/apps/sbt/bin/sbt
```

So what I need here is some environment variable that tells cygwin a set of potential extensions to file names:

Something along the lines of:

```
export EXE_EXTENSIONS=CMD,cmd,EXE,exe,BAT,bat
```

Answer (score 1):

you can run the following command

```
cmd /c <executable>
```

For example, I wanted to run the mysql (mysql.exe) present inside the C:\installedSoft\xampp\mysql\bin directory. It works when tested in [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) and it works fine as expected.  Ensure the executable is in your PATH environment variable.

which will run the windows native executable files on the Cygwin like shell utilities.

Comment: The question mentioned _not_ including the extension.

Comment: Thanksk @javadba. I have edited the answer. In fact this trick works for the executable without the extension as well.